# If different in htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, if-statement

I have a question about htaccess rule.
I need to execute a rule only if url is different from url that I set...

For example I have this code in my htcess:

`RewriteRule ^/?([^/]+)/160-chloe-duraate-lo-shopping/detail/(.*) https://www.allevamentochihuahua.com/foto-album-nostri-chihuahua/160-chloe-duraate-lo-shopping/detail/$2 [R=301,NC,L]`

RewriteRule ^/?([^/]+)/?([^/]+)/160-chloe-duraate-lo-shopping/detail/(.*) https://www.allevamentochihuahua.com/foto-album-nostri-chihuahua/160-chloe-duraate-lo-shopping/detail/$3 [R=301,NC,L]

I want that these rules run only if url visiter is different from foto-album-nostri-chihuahua/160-chloe-duraate-lo-shopping/detail/?([^/]+)

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a rewriting condition to prevent a rewriting loop:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/foto-album-nostri-chihuahua/160-chloe-duraate-lo-shopping/detail/([^/]+)/?$
RewriteRule ^/?([^/]+)/?([^/]+)/160-chloe-duraate-lo-shopping/detail/(.*) https://www.allevamentochihuahua.com/foto-album-nostri-chihuahua/160-chloe-duraate-lo-shopping/detail/$3 [R=301,NC,L]
```

It is a good idea to start out with a 302 temporary redirection and only change that to a 301 permanent redirection later, once you are certain everything is correctly set up. That prevents caching issues while trying things out...